# Two brothers and a window

Tags: story-identification

I don't know if I'm making this up or not but I remember hearing a story about two maybe it was three brothers living in one room with one window and only one brother got to look outside the window and he discribed everything to the other brother(s). That same brother that looked out the window was ill and so he had to take pills every day before he slept so what the brother(s) did was they threw away the pills and so the next day they went to look outside the window and it was nothing but a blank wall. Am I making this up or is this an actual story I've heard of before?

Comment: Was this a fantasy story or just a story about mental illness?

Comment: I've heard this told many times, usually as a morality tale.  The men aren't always brothers, but the one who doesn't sit by the window kills (or in some cases, simply doesn't alert the nurse to a potentially fatal situation) the one by the window because he wants access to the view.  The view is always of a plain brick wall, leaving the reader/listener to draw the conclusion that the first man had been inventing the stories to entertain his friend.  I've seen it multiple times online, but not delivered as an actual story in a book.

Comment: I've seen a version where the man with the window is terminally ill, and finally dies of it, allowing the second man to get the window, and another to be moved into the room -- and starts making up his own stories about what's outside, to entertain the new arrival.

Comment: Although this particular story is not a fantasy one, the collection "More Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark," in which this story appears, has many elements of fantasy within it.

Answer (score 5):

This story is called "The Bed by the Window."

It is from the book "[More Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/413110.More_Scary_Stories_to_Tell_in_the_Dark?from_search=true)" by Alvin Schwartz.

The audio of the story is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0pKCqDhHyA).

Here are three quotes from the story: (George is the name of the man who is originally near the window and Richard is the man in the bed next to George's)

> 'Richard loved to listen to George. But the more George talked about life outside, the more Richard wanted to see it for himself. Yet he knew that only when George died would he have his chance. He wanted to look out that window so badly that one day he decided to kill George. “He is going to die soon, anyway,” he told himself. “What difference would it make?"'
>
> 'All Richard had to do was knock the bottle [of pills] to the floor where George could not reach it.'
>
> 'A few nights later George died just as Richard had planned he would. And the next morning Richard was moved to the bed by the window. Now he would see for himself all the things outside that George had described.
>   After the nurses had left, Richard turned to the window and looked out. But all he could see was a blank brick wall.'

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right answer and how it matches?

Comment: I am well acquainted with the Scary Stories to tell in the Dark books. The characters in this story are not brothers, they are in a retirement home. One of the men is by the window and the man in the bed next to his is very jealous. So, in the middle of the night, he knocks the man's pills on the floor. The next day he is moved to the bed by the window, but all he sees is "a blank brick wall." That's how the story ends. Pretty much exactly what the questioner is describing.

Comment: I have improved my answer

Comment: And you shall have a +1 for your trouble :-)